# Predicted function from GAM with multiple continuous predictors

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I would like to plot a predicted function on the original scale of the data for each continuous predictor in the following GAM model:

```
bird_mod <- gam(bird_count ~ offset(log(sample_area)) + s(site, bs="re") + 
s(proportion_forest) + s(proportion_water) + s(proportion_wetland), 
data=mydata, family=poisson, method="REML")
```

An example of the general type of plot I'm interested in can be found in Pedersen et al. 2019 (pg.13, associated plot and code below). But please note that in my case I am not interested in plotting separate functions for each level of the random effect. I would just like to produce one plot of the predicted function for each continuous predictor in my model (proportion_forest, proportion_water, proportion_wetland, so 3 plots total).

[image]

```
library(mgcv)
library(ggplot2)

CO2 <- transform(CO2, Plant_uo=factor(Plant, ordered=FALSE))

CO2_modG <- gam(log(uptake) ~ s(log(conc), k=5, bs="tp") +
                  s(Plant_uo, k=12, bs="re"),
                data=CO2, method="REML", family="gaussian")

# setup prediction data
CO2_modG_pred <- with(CO2,
                      expand.grid(conc=seq(min(conc), max(conc), length=100),
                                  Plant_uo=levels(Plant_uo)))

# make the prediction, add this and a column of standard errors to the prediction
# data.frame. Predictions are on the log scale.
CO2_modG_pred <- cbind(CO2_modG_pred,
                       predict(CO2_modG, 
                               CO2_modG_pred, 
                               se.fit=TRUE, 
                               type="response"))

# make the plot. Note here the use of the exp() function to back-transform the
# predictions (which are for log-uptake) to the original scale
ggplot(data=CO2, aes(x=conc, y=uptake, group=Plant_uo)) +
  facet_wrap(~Plant_uo) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=exp(fit - 2*se.fit), ymax=exp(fit + 2*se.fit), x=conc),
              data=CO2_modG_pred, 
              alpha=0.3, 
              inherit.aes=FALSE) +
  geom_line(aes(y=exp(fit)), data=CO2_modG_pred) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x=expression(CO[2] ~ concentration ~ (mL ~ L^{-1})),
       y=expression(CO[2] ~ uptake ~ (mu*mol ~ m^{-2})))
```

I have tried adapting the above code to my model by simply including all of my variables in the call to expand.grid, like this:

```
bird_mod_pred<- with(mydata,expand.grid(sample_area=seq(min(sample_area),max(sample_area),length=100),proportion_forest=seq(min(proportion_forest),max(proportion_forest),length=100),proportion_water=seq(min(proportion_water),max(proportion_water),length=100),proportion_wetland=seq(min(proportion_wetland), max(proportion_wetland),length=100),site=levels(site)))
```

However, I receive the following error:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 76.4 Gb.
```

And I have struggled to find an alternative approach. Any comments or advice on the best way to produce these plots for my model would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The size of your `expand.grid` is more than $100^4 = 100\,000\,000$ (it's full factorial) hence the error. Try reducing `length` to a smaller number, say $20$.

Comment: Thanks very much. Runs with no issues now. One more question: how much influence do you think the `length=` argument to `expand.grid` has on the resulting plot? Do you think changing it from 100 to 20 changes the plot/interpretation/accuracy much?

Comment: Depending on the range, it definitely can affect the smoothness of the plots. If I were you, I'd probably fix all but one variable at a certain value, the mean, say, and just vary the other variable. That would allow for more granularity, `length=1000` or so. You could still vary the `site`.

Comment: Good idea. That approach runs and the results are easy to interpret. Thanks again.